# Undefined offset : 1 error on render controller Symfony

Tags: symfony

I am stuck with a problem.
  I have a controller in my Symfony 2.8 project named 'AchievementController'. which I put inside a folder named 'Registration'. I have a action named listAction which use to list all achievements. So my folder structure to controller is

AppBundle > Controller > Registration > AchievementController

I am using a file named list.html.twig to list all achievemets. I am planning to use render controller method to render listAction on another twig named new.html.twig. And my twig is placed at

AppBundle > Resources > views > Registration > Achievements > list.html.twig and

AppBundle > Resources > views > Registration > Achievements > new.html.twig.

My problem is when I used render controller method I got an error

***"An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Notice: Undefined offset: 1") in AppBundle:Registration/Achievement:new.html.twig"***

I have search a lot but every post tell to do the same way I did (I believe), but not working. And I am stuck there. I am attaching my action and twig. Do I want to set some configuration? What mistake I have done?? I have check the same in other projects and it works fine. So I'm confused. (And when I use a folder structure AppBundle > Controller > AchievementController and change code for this, it works fine. Simply it feels like a escape slash problem. But I didn't get any way to fix it.)

- new.html.twig

  `{{ render(controller('AppBundle:Registration/Achievement:list')) }}`
- listAction

  ```
  $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
  $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Registration\Achievement')->findAll();
  return $this->render('AppBundle:Registration/Achievement:list.html.twig', array(
              'entities' => $entities,
  ));
  ```
- list.html.twig

  `{% if entities %}
      --------
      --------
  {% endif %}`

Thanks for every answers.

I have used yml method to generate bundle.
I am attaching my action and controller here. (Removed other actions in controller)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller\Registration;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use AppBundle\Entity\Registration\Achievement;
use AppBundle\Form\Registration\AchievementType;

class AchievementController extends Controller {

    public function listAction()    {

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $entities = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Registration\Achievement')->findAll();
        return $this->render('AppBundle:Registration/Achievement:list.html.twig', array(
                    'entities' => $entities,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post the whole action code for the listAction? with annotations as well

Comment: As seen in the previous comment, I don't know how you defined listAction, but judging from the error message, it is likely to be an argument for listAction.

You called the listAction using render function from twig, hence, you might need to pass an argument which is defined in listAction, if you have that argument.

    {{ render(controller('AppBundle:Registration/Achievement:list', {'var' :value} )) }}

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Comment: ok, I had similar kind of error message with incorrectly written annotations, but that's not your case then. You could still update the question with the full code for your listAction function...

Comment: Sorry for delay, never ask question here. :) Please find my action.

Comment: I've reproduced your situation and do not have any errors. Can you provide the complete code of new.html.twig file?

Comment: @ScalatronMotoroller My requirement is to select complete list of achievements. So I think there is no need of passing any values to action.

Comment: @lllypa actually I have already commented everything else in new.html.twig and same issue occurs. Is there any configurations to change or is there any alternative way to access action by route? something like render uri???

Comment: Can you provide extended Exception details? There's no need to look for some complicated solutions here. I believe there's some tiny silly mistake somewhere. I am curious to find it.)

Comment: Yes, actually that was only my guess...as @lllypa says you could look into the error details then. If error occurs in somewhere else, you could find where it occurs by error stack traces and you could see what line in php or twig file generates that error.

Comment: I believe the same. And sorry I am off work now. I will add here once I find my mistake. ;-)

Comment: Hi all, as you said it was my mistake. One of my colleague has wrote a listener which call kernelControllerEvent in our program. And in which he was only checking condition, when controllers are called from route. I didn't find it before. Now I fix it. Sorry for your time and thanks for your help.